# Add Custom Script to Shopify Liquid Section

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I am working on OutdoorProducts.Com and we have been provided a custom video player widget.

```
<div id="carousel-home"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s) {
__TVPage__ = window.__TVPage__ || {};
__TVPage__.config = __TVPage__.config || {};
__TVPage__.config["carousel-home"] = {
loginid: "1759226",
channel: {"id":"179996403"},
targetEl : "carousel-home",
api_base_url: "//api.tvpage.com/v1"
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var js = d.createElement(s),
fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
js.src = '//widgets-outdoorproducts-com.netlify.com/tvpwidget/carousel- 
home/index.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}, false);
}(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

I was able to put this code in the index file but because Shopify uses a theme customizer with sections I was only able to add it to the top or bottom of the home page content and ideally I would like this under the main banner.

Our shopify theme has a section that can be used for "CUSTOM HTML" but will not display the widget if I add that code in there.

I have figured out how to create my own "section" for the theme editor using a copy of the "Custom Content" section

```html
{%- if section.settings.hidden_section -%}{%- capture check_admin -%}{{ content_for_header  }}{%- endcapture -%}<style> #shopify-section-{{ section.id }} { {%- if check_admin contains 'design_mode' -%}opacity: .5;filter: alpha(opacity=50){%- else -%}display: none !important{%- endif -%}}</style>{%- endif -%}
{%- if section.settings.section_margin_top != blank or section.settings.section_margin_bottom != blank or section.settings.section_border != blank -%}
{%- assign s_margin_top = section.settings.section_margin_top | remove: ' ' | join: ' ' -%}
{%- assign s_margin_bottom = section.settings.section_margin_bottom | remove: ' ' | join: ' ' -%}
{%- assign s_border = section.settings.section_border | remove: ' ' | split: '-' | join: ' ' -%}
{%- endif -%}
{%- capture style_block_section -%}
   {%- if section.settings.section_margin_top != blank or section.settings.section_margin_bottom != blank or section.settings.section_padding_top != blank or section.settings.section_padding_right != blank or section.settings.section_padding_left != blank or section.settings.section_padding_bottom != blank or section.settings.section_bg_color != blank or section.settings.section_bg_image != blank or section.settings.section_border != blank -%}
   <style type="text/css">.gl_custom_{{section.id}}{ {%- if section.settings.section_margin_top != blank -%} margin-top: {{s_margin_top}} !important;{%- endif -%}{%- if section.settings.section_margin_bottom != blank -%} margin-bottom: {{s_margin_bottom}} !important;{%- endif -%}{%- if section.settings.section_padding_top != blank -%}padding-top: {{section.settings.section_padding_top}} !important;{%- endif-%}{%- if section.settings.section_padding_right != blank -%}padding-right: {{section.settings.section_padding_right}} !important;{%- endif-%}{%- if section.settings.section_padding_bottom != blank -%}padding-bottom: {{section.settings.section_padding_bottom}} !important;{%- endif-%}{%- if section.settings.section_padding_left != blank -%}padding-left: {{section.settings.section_padding_left}} !important; {%- endif -%}{%- if section.settings.section_bg_color != blank -%}background-color: {{ section.settings.section_bg_color }} !important;{%- endif -%}{%- if section.settings.section_bg_image != blank -%}{%- assign image = section.settings.section_bg_image -%}{%- assign image_size = image.width | append:'x' -%} background-image: url({%-include 'gl_image_format',src: image , size: image_size -%}) !important; background-position: center !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-size: cover !important;{%- endif -%}{%- if section.settings.section_border != blank and section.settings.section_border_color != blank -%}border-width: {{ s_border }} !important; border-color: {{section.settings.section_border_color}} !important; border-style: {{section.settings.section_border_style}} !important{%- endif -%} }</style>
   {%- endif -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
{{style_block_section}}
<div id="carousel-home"></div>
{%- schema -%}
  {
    "name": "TvPage",
    "class": "index-section gl_custom_html_home",
    "settings": [
      {
         "type": "html",
         "id": "code",
         "label": "HTML",
         "default": "<p>Use this text to share information about your brand with your customers. Describe a product, share announcements, or welcome customers to your store.</p>"
      },
    {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "== Design Options"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "section_margin_top",
        "label": "Margin top",
        "info": "60px"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "section_margin_bottom",
        "label": "Margin bottom",
        "info": "60px"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "section_padding_top",
        "label": "Padding top",
        "info": "60px"
      },
{
        "type": "text",
        "id": "section_padding_right",
        "label": "Padding right",
        "info": "60px"
      },
{
        "type": "text",
        "id": "section_padding_bottom",
        "label": "Padding bottom",
        "info": "60px"
      },
{
        "type": "text",
        "id": "section_padding_left",
        "label": "Padding left",
        "info": "60px"
      },
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "== Basel Extras"
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "hidden_section",
        "label": "Disable Section?",
        "info": "If checked the section won't be visible on the public side of your website. You can switch it back any time.",
        "default": false
      }
    ],
    "presets": [
      {
        "name": "TvPage",
        "category": "Advanced layout"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
<script>
(function(d, s) {
  __TVPage__ = window.__TVPage__ || {};
  __TVPage__.config = __TVPage__.config || {};
  __TVPage__.config["carousel-home"] = {
    loginid: "1759226",
    channel: {"id":"179996403"},
    targetEl : "carousel-home",
    api_base_url: "//api.tvpage.com/v1",
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var js = d.createElement(s),
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js.src = '//widgets-outdoorproducts-com.netlify.com/tvpwidget/carousel-home/index.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }, false);
}(document, 'script'));
</script>
{% endjavascript %}
```

but I cannot get the widget to appear. It seems like I would need to add it in-between the "SCHEMA" tags but if I do then it I get this message "Error: Invalid JSON in tag 'schema'"

Is there a way to make this happen?